# Convert Haskell ByteStrings to C++ std::string

Tags: c++, string, haskell, ffi

I want to convert strict `ByteStrings` from Haskell into C++'s `std::string` to pass it to a C++ library via [the FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction). As the `ByteString` may contain `NULL` characters, converting into a `CString` as an intermediate step is not viable. What is the right approach here?

**current solution**

Thanks for the answers so far. I hoped for a canonical solution for that task, but maybe it does not exist yet :)

Some [c++ library documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) says following:

> string ( const char * s, size_t n );
>
> Content is initialized to a copy of the string formed by the first n characters in the array of characters     pointed by s.

Therefore one can write such a function which copies once from the ByteString to construct a std::string

```
foreign import ccall unsafe toCCString_ :: CString -> CUInt -> IO (Ptr CCString)
toCCString :: ByteString -> IO (Ptr CCString)
toCCString bs =
    unsafeUseAsCStringLen bs $ \(cstring,len) ->
    toCCString_ cstring (fromIntegral len)
```

The C++ code accompanying `toCCString_` then would just look like Neil and Alan pointed out.

Comment: We need _far_ more information about how you intend to interface the two languages.

Comment: I edited my question a bit, but I'm not sure what information you mean.

Comment: "via the FFI"'s what we needed.

Comment: Sorry that I previously edited "`CString`". Didn't know at the time that it's a specific thing. Have reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C-String.html) is great!

> type CString = Ptr CChar
>
> > A C string is a reference to an array of C characters terminated by NUL.
>
> type CStringLen = (Ptr CChar, Int)
>
> > A string with explicit length information in bytes instead of a terminating NUL (allowing NUL characters in the middle of the string).

If you use a `CStringLen`, you should have no problems. (In fact, I recommend this because [interfacing C++ and Haskell is a nightmare](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cxx_foreign_function_interface).)

`NULL` characters in the middle of `char` buffers is only problematic when you don't know how long the data contained therein *should* be (and thus have to traverse it looking for a `NULL`, hoping that that's the intended end of the data).

Answer (score 2):

Does your `ByteString` (with its nulls) actually represent a text string?  If not, then `std::vector<char>` would be more appropriate.

That being said, the internal representation of std::string does not depend on null termination so you can have a std::string with null characters in it.  Use the [constructor with the prototype string(const char * s, size_t n)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).  Just don't depend on .c_str() to interface with anything expecting a null terminated c string.

Comment: The output of Binary or Cereal has headers containing NULLs where needed to indicate the size of the data following. Whether this data is just textual data is not predetermined.

Comment: @Long: It sounds like std:vector would be a be a better fit to your use.  Are there any actual string-specific functions that you use on the buffer?

Comment: I'm writing bindings to the Xapian search library and it internally stores any user-defined extra information (from simple strings to complicated data structures) as std::string. Knowing this I assume using std::vector would just be an unnecessary intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

C++ strings can contain null characters. Assuming you have something like this:

```
char s1[] ="string containing nulls";
```

then you can convert to a std::string

```
string s2( s1, length_of_s1 );
```

The problem is how to get `length_of_s1` - obviously you can't use strlen, or similar functions, but presumably your strings are maintaining a length indicator you can use.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question in any way.